# Laravel 5.1 - Are Multiple URI's Possible?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

what I want to do is something similar to this:

```
Route::get(['uri1','uri2'], function(){ /* these two uri's do the same thing */  });
```

Does Laravel support this?  Google has let me down on this problem.

Comment: Why don't you try and let us know about the result?

Answer (score 4):

You can point them to the same function on a controller:

```
Route::get('uri1','YourController@yourFunction');
Route::get('uri2','YourController@yourFunction');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use route patterns, which support regex. The nice thing about this is that the URL that they use is now available to you as a parameter as well:

```
Route::pattern('name', 'uri1|uri2');
Route::get('{name}', function($name) {
    // do something with $name
});
```

If you want the regex pattern to only apply to this route and not globally, you can also write it like this:

```
Route::get('{name}', function ($name) { })
    ->where(['name' => 'uri1|uri2']);
```

Another example; it would be good to know what your actual URIs are so that I can make a real suggestion:

```
Route::pattern('name', 'uri[0-9]+');
Route::get('{name}', function() { });
```

Just be careful that your regex patterns aren't too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember, that a `.php` with routes is still a PHP script:

```php
foreach ([
             'the_first_uri',
             'another_address',
         ]
         as $route) {
    /*
     * Each route will call the same controller/action
     */
    Route::get($route, 'YourController@anAction');
}
```

One can say, that it's not very "readable", but it has a few pros:

- DRY: one doesn't repeat the fragment that adds a new route; think of a case when you want to just rename the action or the controller
- VCS: using arrays that enumerate possible values instead of regular expressions makes your commits and repository history cleaner, i.e. if you add/change/delete a route, you just add/modify/delete a corresponding line

However, I believe that in most cases such `foreach` will be a little exaggeration ;)